# Dealing with Empty Fields

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, stormcrawler

I am new to stormcrawler and elasticsearch in general. I am currently using stormcrawler 2.0 to index website data (including non-HTML items such as PDF's and Word Documents) into elasticsearch. In some cases, the metadata of PDF's or Word documents do not contain a title so the field is stored blank/null in elasticsearch. This is unfortunately causing issues in the webapp I am using to display search results (search-ui). Is there a way I can have stormcrawler insert a default value of "Untitled" into the title field if none exists in the metadata?

I understand that elasticsearch has a null_value field parameter, but if I understand correctly that parameter cannot be used for text fields and only helps with searching.

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure `null_value` can be used for text fields. The only restriction `null_value` has according to the latest docs is that it must be the same data type as the field. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to write a custom ParseFilter to give an arbitrary value to any missing key or a key with an empty value. The StormCrawler code has quite a few examples of [ParseFilters](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/parse/filter), see also [the WIKI](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/ParseFilters).

The same could be done as a custom Bolt placed between the parser and the indexer; grab the metadata and normalise to your heart's content.

Comment: Julien, thank you for your guidance on this issue and for all your hard work on stormcrawler. Your tutorial videos have been a huge help and I hope to see more in the future.

Comment: you're welcome Will. Please get in touch if you want the next video to cover anything in particular.